# Items are not shown in ListView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am very new to Android Studio. I am working with webview. I wanna create bookmarks and history list.
I tried a code from internet source.
I double checked my coding and it does not look bad..
In my application there is a menu item for adding particular url to bookmarks and separate menu item to show bookmark page when clicked on it in main activity.
According to my knowledge code is correct. but I cant see added urls on bookmark page activity.
I tried different ways mentioned on internet to solve this..but nothing worked for me..

I created a "websites" class to get string of webview
Here below the class ("websites")

```
public class websites
{
private int id;
private String url;
private String title;
private ImageView image;

public websites(String url)
{
    this.url = url;
}
public websites(String url, String title)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.title = title;
}
public int getId()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl()
{
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url)
{
    this.url = url;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

public ImageView getImage()
{
    return image;
}

public void setImage(ImageView image)
{
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

Here below the "mydbhandlerbook" class for bookmark database

```
public class mydbhandlerbook extends SQLiteOpenHelper     // For Bookmarks
{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bookmark.db"; // name of the file
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bookmarks";  // name of the table
public static final String  COLUMN_ID = "column_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "url";

public mydbhandlerbook(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
{
    super (context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +"("+ COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +COLUMN_NAME +" TEXT "+")";
    db.execSQL (query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL ("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate (db);
}

/**
 * Adding new raw to database
 * @param website
 */
public void addurl(websites website)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues ();
    values.put (COLUMN_NAME,website.getUrl ());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase ();
    db.insert (TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close ();
}

/**
 *   Deleting URL
 */
public void deleteurl(String url)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase ();
    db.execSQL ("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+COLUMN_NAME+"=\""+url +"\";" );
}

/**
 *  Print out the History as String
 */
public List<String> databasetostring()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase ();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME;

    List<String> dbstring = new ArrayList<> ();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery (query,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst ();
    int i = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToNext ())
    {
        do {
            if (cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex (COLUMN_NAME))!=null)
            {
                String bstring = "";
                bstring += cursor.getString (cursor.getColumnIndex ("url"));
                dbstring.add (bstring);
            }
        }while (cursor.moveToNext ());
    }
    return dbstring;
}
}
```

Here follow is the "bookmarks" activity

```
public class bookmarks extends AppCompatActivity
{
mydbhandlerbook bookmark =  new mydbhandlerbook (this,null,null,1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.bookmarks);

    final List<String> books = bookmark.databasetostring ();
    if (books.size ()>0)
    {
        ArrayAdapter myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,books);
        ListView mylist = findViewById (R.id.bookmark_list);
        mylist.setAdapter (myadapter);

        mylist.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String url = books.get (position);
                //Intent intent = getParentActivityIntent ();//??
                //intent.putExtra ("bookmark_url",url);
                //startActivity (intent);
                //finish ();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

I placed following piece of codes inside of main activity,

```
mydbhandlerbook bookmark = new mydbhandlerbook (this,null,null,1);
websites yandex = new websites ("yandex.com");
bookmark.addurl (yandex);
websites google = new websites ("google.com");
bookmark.addurl (google);
bookmark.addurl (baidu);
websites yahoo = new websites ("yahoo.com");
bookmark.addurl (yahoo);
```

When i clicked the bookmarks menu item on tool bar menu, the "bookmarks" activity opens. Listview is shown..But Items are not shown..

I have no idea why it is not shown.
Anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: This is the youtube playlist where I got the code from,       (part 24 to part 26)                                                                           Link :   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOqrKK4XKUs&list=PLe3j2Wt60kR9BMWlWjOvlkK0TZvI8H-fJ&index=24

Comment: android studio is an IDE. it helps you build android apps, but it doesn't make a difference at all to your code. if you're asking about the IDE, use the android-studio tag. if you're asking about _android_ then use the _android_ tag. i've fixed it for you this time

Comment: got it.......thank you.

Comment: no problem, only reason i'm saying this is because it really does make a difference to your question as people might not find it if you just use the android_studio tag, hope you find an answer

Comment: Are you sending bookmark from mainActivity to bookmark intent.Do correct this line:Intent intent = new Intent(view.getActivity(),MainActivity.class);//Why have you commented this line?

Comment: Yed.. I want open corresponding url when clicked on a item url in listview.. Its ok.. The thing is, items are not shown in Listview 

Comment: .getActivity() showing error: cannot resolve methode